# SimpleForm Check Existing has_many Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have two models connected by a join table: Users and Agencies (joined by AgencyUserRelationships).  A user has many relationships, each relationship having one agency, but they do not necessarily have relationships to *all* Agencies.

I want to create a Simpleform for a user which displays all the agencies as a list of checkboxes, where the existing relationships are already checked.  Submitting the form updates/deletes existing relationships if they are unchecked and creates new ones if they get checked.  This sounded like a job for `accepts_nested_attributes_for` but my attempts are failing (see below)

User.rb

```
has_many :agency_user_relationships
accepts_nested_attributes_for: agency_user_relationships
```

AgencyUserRelationship.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :agency
```

Simple Form Code

```
= simple_form_for user do |f|
  = f.input :agency_user_relationships, collection: Agency.all, as: :check_boxes, label: t(:agencies)
  = button_tag type: :submit, "Add"
```

This ends up giving me a form that has one row for each Agency (which is what I want), but the existing relationships aren't checked.

I looked at [Simpleforms docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models), but following the example there just gives me a form with two rows for editing the nested resource, which isn't really what I want, I don't think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was pretty close.  I changed f.input to f.association and Rails knew what to do.

It turned my simpleform code into

```
= simple_form_for user do |f|
  = f.association :agency_user_relationships, as: :check_boxes, collection: Agency.all, label: t(:agencies)
  = button_tag type: :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary controls' do
    = t(:add_agency)
```

Now, the form shows up with all the Agencies that exist, but the ones which already have relationships with my user are checked by default.  The rest is controller code.